# Why this CSS <li css={css` border: 1px solid #e1e1e1; padding: 2rem;`} > not applying in my React app?

Tags: css, reactjs

i need apply this:

```
                    <li key={`${comentario.usuarioId}-${i}`} 
                        css={css`
                            border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
                            padding: 2rem;
                        `}
                    >
```

without import css modules

Comment: because the style attribute is not called `css`?

Comment: `style={{ border: 1px solid #e1e1e1; padding: 2rem; }}`. I don't see how your code could have worked in other projects.

Comment: When applied to the `style` attribute of an element, it might have worked in another project because that project was dependant on a css-in-js library (styled-components, emotion, etc) that exposed a `css` helper function as part of its api. It is nothing to do with react or react versions.

Comment: Well, I suppose that's half of the problem. These libraries purport to help but really they just obscure things and make code harder to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the style attribute with a object to set a inline style of element, like example below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>
      <ul>
        <li style={{ "border": "1px solid #e1e1e1", "padding": "2rem" }}>some item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>);
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```